# Fixed rows sorting in datatables

Tags: javascript, sorting, rows, datatables

I want to establish some fixed rows in head of the datatable.

This is my datatable settings:

```
var oTable = $('#transactions').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [ [0,'desc'] ],
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": true, 
    "aaSorting": [[3,'desc']], // default search colums
    //            "aaSortingFixed": [[3,'desc']],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "asStripeClasses": [ 'monitoring-table-new' ],
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumns": [
        {   "sType": "custom",
            "sClass": "td-date-size-cell",
            "fnRender": function ( oObj, sVal ) {
                return '<div class="monitoring-head-new leadencolor"><div class="form-border"><span class="date"><em>' + sVal + '</em></span></div></div>';
            }
        },
        {   "sType": "custom",
            "sClass": "td-transaction-size-cell",
            "fnRender": function ( oObj, sVal ) {
                return '<div class="monitoring-head-new leadencolor"><div class="form-border"><span class="transaction"><em>' + sVal + '</em></span></div></div>';
            }
        },
        {   "sType": "custom",
            "sClass": "td-client-size-cell",
            "fnRender": function ( oObj, sVal ) {
                return '<div class="monitoring-head-new leadencolor"><div class="form-border"><span class="client"><div>' + sVal + '</div></span></div></div>';
            } 
        },
        {   "sType": "custom",
            "sClass": "td-value-size-cell",
            "fnRender": function ( oObj, sVal ) {
                return '<div class="monitoring-head-new leadencolor"><div class="form-border"><span class="value"><em>' + sVal + '</em></span></div></div>';
            }
        },
        {   "sType": "custom",
            "sClass": "td-status-size-cell",
            "fnRender": function ( oObj, sVal ) {
                return '<div class="monitoring-head-new leadencolor"><div class="form-border"><span class="status"><div>' + sVal + '</div></span></div></div>';
            }
        },
    ],
    "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo url_for('@test?sf_format=json'); ?>',  

} );
```

I have done in the following way:

```
   jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-asc']  = function(x,y) {
        if (x.indexOf("MY VALUE") != -1) return -1; // keep this row at top
        if (y.indexOf("MY VALUE") != -1) return 1; // keep this row at top

        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
    };

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-desc'] = function(x,y) {
        if (x.indexOf("MY VALUE") != -1) return 1; // keep this row at top
        if (y.indexOf("MY VALUE") != -1) return -1; // keep this row at top

        return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    };
```

This will keep in top position the rows which have "MY VALUE" in text. But the problem is that when I sort on other column, the "fixed" row is not remaining on top of the table.

Any solutions?

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: Here is a code example in jsbin - http://jsbin.com/eroyac/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easy, one thing you could do is mix your custom sorting with a [custom datasource sorting](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting#how_to_data_source) tha customizes your datasource

```
// var oTable;
var onTopValues = new Array("Litige", "5410");

/*  disable asc sorting for specific rows */
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-asc']  = function(x,y) {

        if (isOnTop(x)) return -1; // keep this row at top
        if (isOnTop(y)) return 1; // keep this row at top

        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-desc'] = function(x,y) {
        if (isOnTop(x)) return -1; // keep this row at top
        if (isOnTop(y)) return 1; // keep this row at top

        return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};

function isOnTop(s) {
        // search for on top values
        for (var i = 0; i < onTopValues.length; i++) {
          if (s === onTopValues[i]) {
            return true; 
          }
        }

        return false;
}
//custom datasource
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['custom-ontop'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn )
{
  var aData = [];
  //prepare the data
  $('td:eq('+iColumn+')',  oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings)).each(function(){
    //If the last column of this row should stay on top, return the value of the 
    //last row as datasource
    if(isOnTop($(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text())){
       aData.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:last').text());
    }else{
        //otherwise return this row as datasource
         aData.push($(this).text());
    }
  });

  return aData;
};


$(document).ready(function() {

          /* Apply custom classes to table headers */
        $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sSortAsc = "custom_asc";
        $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sSortDesc = "custom_desc";


  oTable = $('#transactions').dataTable({       
        "aoColumnDefs": [ { aTargets: [0,1,2,3], sType: "custom"}] ,
         "aoColumns": [
                { "sSortDataType": "custom-ontop" },
                { "sSortDataType": "custom-ontop" },
                { "sSortDataType": "custom-ontop" },
                { "sSortDataType": "custom-ontop" },
                { "sSortDataType": "custom-ontop" }
            ],
        "aaSorting": [],
        "aaData": [
            [ "2012-01-2", "2", "Local <br>0312313213", 20, "Litige" ],
            [ "2012-03-22", "25", "Local <br>35313313213", 5540, "Valid" ],
            [ "2012-01-2", "2", "Local <br>0312313213", 10, "Valid" ],
            [ "2012-03-22", "25", "Local <br>35313313213", 5410, "Valid" ]
        ]
    });    
});
```

Basically you are still using your sorting function but you pass them a custom datasource that forces the values to stay on top. This assume that you are sorting on the last column, but you can add your logic to it.

http://jsbin.com/eroyac/4/edit#preview

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it - in DataTables all rows can be sorted, you can't 'freeze' into place a particular row (i.e. always position 0) unless you customise the sorting. So to alter the sorting of the rows, you need to customs the sorting functions as you wish. sType and a custom sorting function only might be enough for most cases, but you could use aaSortingFixed, aDataSort and various other options to assist the sorting.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't sort it. Use a `tfoot` like so -

```
<thead> ... </thead>
<tfoot style="display: table-row-group"> ... </tfoot>
<tbody> ... </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

This way i can lock the first row, and the sorting only affects the row after this one. Check this page for other options : http://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed

```js
$('#budgytbl').dataTable({
  "orderFixed": [ 0, 'asc' ]
})
```

```html
<table id="budgytbl"...

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td id="input-name"></td>
    <td id="input-parent"></td> 
  </tr>

  @foreach ($categories as $category)
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
  @endforeach
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simplier solution.

I create the second `tbody` in my table and just move all rows I need to persist in that another `tbody` like so:

```
initComplete: function() {
    var self = this;

    var api = this.api();
    api.rows().eq(0).each(function(index) {
        var row = api.row(index);
        if (row.data()...) { // condition here
            var $row_to_persist = $(row.node());
            var $clone = $row_to_persist .clone();

            $(self).find('tbody:last').append($clone);

            $total_row.remove();
            row.remove();
            api.draw();
        }
    });
}
```