# Shiny/Datatable: leave row on fixed position while sorting

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have a simple datatable table in Shiny report, say

```
renderDataTable(mtcars)
```

is it possible to make one of the rows (e.g. the `Volvo 142E`) have fixed position (always stay on the bottom), i.e. not to move while sorting the table using the up/down arrows, no matter by what column we sort? I assume that the row is uniquely identifiable, so there is no problem with pointing the row that should stay fixed.

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939889/fixed-rows-sorting-in-datatables) has a solution for this problem outside shiny. You might have to use a callback argument to feed that custom function to your DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

```
    # this pgm will hopefully download time-series data from yahoo.finance
   # from a table listing the sp500 you will select 3 rows
   # one row designated by the setResponse button is the response variable to be predicted
   # in a regression
   # the next two rows will determine the explanatory vars  and is set by
   # the user pressing the selEVars button      

                                  #   server.R
   library(shiny)
   library(googlesheets)
   library(DT)
   # the google sheet is a great way to store data
   sheet <- gs_title( 'tickerSymbols' )
   sp500 = gs_read_csv(sheet)   # it's a google sheet

   shinyServer(   function(input, output, session ) {

   # define sp500 symbol table for stock history lookup
   output$sp500Table = DT::renderDataTable( sp500 , escape=T )

    rsIndex = eventReactive( input$setResponse, {
    if( length( input$sp500Table_cell_clicked$row ) > 0 ) {
         setResponse = input$sp500Table_cell_clicked$row  
         return( setResponse )
        } # end if
    }  # end code chunk
   )   # end obs evt fun
    # this sets the expl. vars  set in ui.R
   eVarIndex= eventReactive( input$selEVars, {
   if( length( input$sp500Table_rows_selected ) >= 2 ) {
   selEVars = input$sp500Table_rows_selected 
   return( selEVars[2:3] )
   }  # end if
   }  # end code chunk for obs evt
   )   # obs evt fun
  # here is the probable location of problem
  # this data.frame does not show up unless i select 4 rows!
  observeEvent( input$sp500Table_rows_selected ,  {
   if( length(eVarIndex() ) >= 2  && length( rsIndex())>=1 ) {
        rs=c( rsIndex(), eVarIndex() )
    cc = c( 'response', 'expl. var. 1', 'expl. var. 2' )   
    sel.df =  data.frame( description=cc, sp500[ rs ,  ] )
    output$tabO = renderTable( sel.df  )
    } # endif
    }  # end chunk

      }  # end server chunk fun
    )   # end shinyserver fun

      # the ui follows
      #  ui.R

   library(shiny)
   library(shinyBS)

   shinyUI(

   fluidPage(
   tags$style(type='text/css', ".shiny-table { color: blue; font-weight:       
   bold;  font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px;}")
   ,  # ,

    bsCollapsePanel(  
         h5("Select a response and 2 explanatory variables") 
  , # ,
     # i hope the labels are self explanatory as to the objective
     actionButton( inputId = 'setResponse', label = 'set response variable'        
      )
   ,  # ,
     actionButton( inputId = 'selEVars', label = 'select 2 explantory 
                    variables' )
      ,  # ,
         actionButton( input='bldModel', label='build predictive model' )
        ,  # , 
    h6( 'selected variables for model construction' )
  ,  # ,    # and the problem table appears here!
    tableOutput( outputId='tabO' )
    ,  # ,
    br()
    , # ,
         DT::dataTableOutput( "sp500Table" ) 

      )  # end panel
     )    # end page

   )  # end UI
```