# Fixed top row when sort in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm building a website for storing files and here is my UI
[image]

When I sort, the ".." row will be the bottom row and it's is undesirable effects.
I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939889/fixed-rows-sorting-in-datatables) but seem likes he used the old API.
Can anybody show me how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
Here is my code to initialize datatable

```
var tableFolder = $('#tableFolder').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        {"width": "50%", "targets": 0},
        {"width": "25%", "targets": 1},
        {"width": "25%", "targets": 2}
    ],
    aaSorting: [],
    deferRender: true,
    scrollY: 560,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: true,
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ajax: url,
    fnCreatedRow: function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', aData[3]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide your code to review and searching solution.

Comment: I've updated code. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: @AnhN.Nguyen did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

This has an answer at the datatables [blog](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-12-22).

Add the plugin to your page

```
//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/absolute.js
```

If you want to order a datatable and keep all rows with the text 'Unknown' in the first column at the top of your datatable.

```
var nameType = $.fn.dataTable.absoluteOrder( 'Unknown' );

$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [
        { targets: 0, type: nameType }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: This only applies if sorting on column `0`, if you sort any other column this doesn't preserve the top row.

Comment: @AlexF Does adding the column index to the targets fix the issue?